# Ошибка: Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: массивы, pascal, turbopascal

Имеется задача: ввёдённый пользователем массив разделить на три других, в которых числа сгруппированы согласно их остатку от деления на 3, а потом эти три массива соединить в один.

```
 if M[i] mod 3 = 0 then begin j:=j+1;b[j]:=M[i];end;
 if M[i] mod 3 = 1 then begin a:=a+1;c[a]:=M[i];end;
 if M[i] mod 3 = 2 then begin e:=e+1;d[e]:=M[i];end; {на этой строке выдаёт ошибку}

 M[i]:= b[j]+c[a]+d[e];
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Значит, массив d маловат.... И вряд ли объединение массивов означает то, что у вас в последней строке.

Comment: Весь код программы можно увидеть?